# Angular2 cast a nested json object to a type

Tags: json, angular

I'm using Angular2 and typescript. WebApi returns JSON and I would like to cast into a certain type.

Here is my type:

```ts
export interface Content {
  title: string;
  description: string;
}
```

The web api returns following JSON String.

```ts
[
  {
    "contentId": "123",
    "contentJson": {
      "title": "ABC",
      "description": "ABC Description"
    },
    "cultureName": "en-us"
  },
  {
    "contentId": "124",
    "contentJson": {
      "title": "DEF",
      "description": "DEF Description"
    },
    "cultureName": "en-us"
  },
  {
    "contentId": "222",
    "contentJson": {
      "title": "ZZZ",
      "description": "ZZZ Description"
    },
    "cultureName": "en-us"
  },
  {
    "contentId": "125",
    "contentJson": {
      "title": "AAA",
      "description": "AAA Description"
    },
    "cultureName": "en-us"
  }
]
```

My required type is inside the contentJson object. How can I cast in Angular 2?

Comment: For what purpose do you want to case? Casting by itself won't do anything. Casting is only to tell your IDE and other development tools that it's safe to assume that some value is of a specific type. At runtime it will be ignored - especially if it is an interface you cast to.

Comment: Actually, I just want to display contentJson object in my list.

Comment: What list? What problem did you run into?

Comment: I want to get following array:
{
      "title": "ABC",
      "description": "ABC Description"
},
{
      "title": "DEF",
      "description": "DEF Description"
},
{
      "title": "ZZZ",
      "description": "ZZZ Description" 
},

Comment: So you only want to display these two properties instead of all? I think you should create a new object instance instead. Casting it to your interface won't result in other properties not being shown. As I mentioned above, interfaces are only for your linter and compiler, but are ignored at runtime.

Comment: could you show the example how to get it?

Comment: `var foo = { title: myJson[3].title, description: myJson[3].description] };` and then display `foo` instead of `myJson[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

A cast is made with `<Type>`
Just try this

```
var content = <Content>yourJsonArray[i].contentJson
```